# monitoring most common web browsers c#/vc++/c

Tags: c#, c, winapi, visual-c++

i'm trying to do a download manager just for learning cos i'm new in windows programming,
could someone tell me how to monitor most common web browsers, 
i'd like to implement something like:
http://www.iwisoft.com/videodownloader/video-downloader-features.php
everytime you visit a web page in common browsers detects all video files in the web page and allow you to download or not the file, any idea how to do that without building an app for every browser, which is the best language to do it c#/vc++/managed/unmanaged,
i'm learning and using a mix of all to do other parts like download files, add rules to firewall or modify the registry
thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the thing that someone does "for learning", and will involve a lot of low level  stuff, and won;t actually be representative of "Windows programming".

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know a neat way of doing this, but you could try the following :

- Enumerate the name of the current window using `GetForegroundWindow`.
- Check if the name you get using `GetWindowText` matches the usual name of the browser.
- If it is a browser, moniter the clipboard and check for hyperlinks
- then do your download stuff.

I program in C++ and assembly, but I wouldn't be able to advice you on the programming language since I don't have any experience with C#. But since you are new, I would suggest starting out with basic stuff. As pointed out in your comment, this is not something that can be achieved easily.

Comment: thanks for your response, i'll try what you say i've done some c# and vc++ parsers and work well for images or any text from a web page but not for videos cos sometimes it's really difficult to get real url,

Comment: i'm testing this: http://www.winpcap.org/ and it's a really good product to monitor pc traffic and get flash streams, the only problem is that you can´t get dll for free you have to work with winpcap installed in your pc i don´t like that if someone knows a free product like that to work with like a dll please post a link

Comment: @thorweiller 
Once again I don't know much about it, but when I installed Wireshark, it also installed Winpcap,as a driver/service. This leads me to think that there is some kernel level stuff going on. If so, you may have to create a filter driver to filter all network data. But bear in mind that you will have to program in kernel land, and that can be extremely tedious. An alternative would be to create some kind of plugin for each of the browsers and then work your way from there.